# If $u$ solves Dirichlet problem $-\Delta u =f$, what is known about $fu$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ be the weak solution of
$$-\Delta u = f$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$$

Is there anything known about the sign of $fu$ a.e?

Comment: I think the sign of $\int_\Omega fu d\sigma$ is positive. But I have no idea about $fu$. I think it is complicated.

Comment: Do you have any particular $f$ in mind? In this generality there is nothing to say about this sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lion said: the *integral* of $fu$ is nonnegative, but not because of any pointwise bound for $fu$. It's integration by parts: $\int_\Omega (-u\,\Delta u ) = \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2\ge 0$.

To give a simple example: let $u (x)=x(x-1)(x-4) $  in one dimension, with $\Omega=(0,4)$. Then $f(x) = -u''(x) = 10-6x$. The product $fu$ changes sign at $1$ and at $5/3$:

[image: counterexample]